Why does Gorgonzola Dolce have such prominent little tubes compared to other blues?
Some background: I quite enjoy getting Gorgonzola Dolce (which, based on my understanding on the distinction in nomenclature, I suspect should be called Gorgonzola Cremificato because it's so often just so melty) from my local Wegmans because it's consistently melty and creamy and salty in a way I just adore. But I notice something interesting about that cheese in particular I don't with other blues (which I also eat all the time, as I am a big blue cheese fan)- the presence of long blue tubes/veins that look kind of wormy, taste a bit salty and a bit bluey, and have a texture somewhere between tyrosine crystals and Camembert rind (apologies for the presumably poor descriptive terminology- I do know more than the average person about cheese, but I'm no expert in this realm). I think they're delicious and break up my delightfully melty Gorgonzola Dolce wonderfully, so this isn't a negative question at all but mere curiosity:
I have no doubt that these are either the paths along which the cheese was pierced or something very similar, but given that other blues have similar piercing procedures, why are they so darn prominent in this particular cheese? Is it just that they're more noticeable given the texture of the cheese (in the sense that their texture/shape would blend in more in harder blues), or is there some other reason they're all pokey and wormy and noticeable in Gorgonzola Dolce in particular? Are they somehow deliberately produced during the production of the cheese? If so, how?
I could swear the tubes don't appear in other blues, but maybe they just blend in with the texture of other blue so well it's almost impossible to observe them separate from the main body of the cheese. If anyone has any information whatsoever, I'd be very interested to learn more.
Also, apologies if this question is kind of hard to understand or get through in any way- it's quite late where I am right now and my sentences always get much longer and more tortuous when I'm tired. It's just that I've wondered this on occasion several times across the past few years (since I entered college and started going to that Wegmans) and wanted to get this question out before I inevitably forgot again.
